# Copying string content to char array

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

I want to copy the content in the string to char array.

Can I use this code `StrLCopy(C, pChar(@S[1]), high(C));`

I am currently using Delphi 2006. Will there be any problems if I upgrade my Delphi version because of Unicode support provided in newer versions?

If not, what can be the code for this conversion?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you're copying a string into an array, prefer [`StrPLCopy`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.StrPLCopy).

```
StrPLCopy(C, S, High(C));
```

That will work in all versions of Delphi, even when Unicode is in effect. The character types of `C` and `S` should be the same; don't try to use that function to convert between Ansi and Unicode characters.

But `StrLCopy` is fine, too. You don't need to have so much pointer code, though. Delphi already knows how to convert a string into a PChar:

```
StrLCopy(C, PChar(S), High(C));
```

Answer (score 7):

This works, in a quick test:

```
var
  ch: array[0..10] of Char;
  c: Char;
  x: Integer;
  st: string;
begin
  s := 'Testing';
  StrLCopy(PChar(@ch[0]), PChar(s), High(ch));
  x := 100;
  for c in ch do
  begin
    Canvas.TextOut(x, 100, c);
    Inc(c, Canvas.TextWidth(c) + 3);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the difference between the two STrlCopy statements

Comment: Thank you Ken for taking time

Comment: The help says: "Warning: The ANSI version of StrLCopy is deprecated. Please use the AnsiStrings unit."

Comment: This answer was written more than a decade ago, and the procedure was not deprecated at that time. If you're getting that waning, then add the AnsiStrings unit to your implementation `uses` clause to stop it. Out of curiosity, why did you choose to comment on my answer instead of the other one, or the question itself?